# Disable Cerberus smoke grenades in ME3

Tags: mass-effect-3, mods

In Mass Effect 3, Cerberus enemies constantly spam smoke grenades. I mean ***constantly***. These grenades do nothing whatsoever because the AI is idiotic; the unit will nearly always just throw the smoke grenade and then sit where it's at behind cover anyway, meaning I just have to wait for the smoke to dissipate to continue the fight.

Is there any way to edit Coalesced.bin to disable the use of smoke grenades entirely? Normally I would never do this in a game as I view it almost as cheating, but there's absolutely no point to these stupid smoke grenades. (For example, even though the explosive grenade spam is just as bad, I wouldn't disable them because they're at least something that has to be avoided, whereas the smoke grenades are just annoying.)

Comment: On some difficulties (at least in multiplayer), the AI will try and use the smoke grenades to distract you while they circle around and approach from another angle or obscure vision of bigger, meaner enemies.  Though I'll grant the grunt AI isn't amazingly sophisticated all around.

Comment: there are 2 weapons mods in game, 1 for see through smoke & 1 for see through wall.

Comment: On Insanity difficulty, smoke grenades are almost exclusively used to obscure advances of enemy squads or heavy machinery. Being ambushed or surrounded by a squad from a smokescreen is the norm and makes them just as important to avoid than fragmentation grenades.